# FormatException when posting data from Flutter app to PHP back-end

Tags: php, sql, flutter, dart

I am developing a Flutter application that takes text from a controller. Upon submitting, it executes a function that posts the data to a PHP back-end, which then inserts the data into a MySQL database.

The problem I'm encountering is an unhandled exception: *"FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)"*.

I am currently just trying to update the first name column in the table, with the ID set to auto increment. I am unsure what is causing this error message.

Here's my Dart function that posts the data:

```dart
postData () async {
    name = nameField.text;
    lastName = lastField.text;

    var urlWeb = Uri.parse('https://sqlfinalproject.000webhostapp.com/insert.php');

    var res = await http.post(urlWeb ,headers: {"Accept":"application/json"},
        body: {
          "name":name,
          "last":lastName,
        }
    );
```

And here's the PHP code that inserts the data:

```php
<?php
require("db.php");

$firstName = $_POST["name"];
$lastName = $_POST["last"];

$querySt = "INSERT INTO project1 (id,firstName,lastName) VALUES('NULL,".$firstName."','".$lastName."')";

$statement = $connection->prepare($querySt);

$statement->execute();

echo json_encode("inserted data");

?>
```

Any insights as to what could be causing this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here is how your query should be run. https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#prepare

Comment: In the sql you have `VALUES('NULL,` which would cause an error in an of itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from trying to convert a non JSON / array / object, respectively a string, to a json and output it. So the error is here.

```php
echo json_encode("inserted data");
```

At this point it would probably be better to pass an assiocative array

```php
echo json_encode(array("message" => "inserted data"));
```

Besides this, there is a problem with your SQL query as well. In the VALUES part of the SQL query, you have written 'NULL,".$firstName."','".$lastName."'. There shouldn't be single quotes around NULL, and you're missing a single quote before $firstName.

```php
$querySt = "INSERT INTO project1 (id,firstName,lastName) 
VALUES(NULL,'".$firstName."','".$lastName."')";
```

You should never write values that come from the user directly into the database without at least validating them.
[Have a look at the PDO perpare bind statements.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)